# Getting an error when populating a list with angular, ngRepeat:dupes

Tags: angularjs

So i am getting the error: ***ngRepeat:dupes***
i am getting the error when i am populating the list with angular.
I have tried to use the *track by index* but when i use this i get another error, and still nothing is getting displayed in the list.
 The error i get when i use *track by index* is: **[filter:notarray]**
Can any of you explain why i get this error?

 Here is my angular script

```
<script>
angular.module('cardList', []).controller('CardController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("/Card/AllCardsList").then(function (list) {
        $scope.names = list.data;
    });
});
```

and here is the list

```
<div ng-app="cardList" ng-controller="CardController">
<p>
    <input type="text" ng-model="test" />
</p>

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in names track by $index | filter:test">
        {{x}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What does the data look like?

Comment: no data is showing. If i move the track by index on the other side of the | then i just get some random html

Answer (score 0):

If `list.data` is returning correctly then this should work.

```
<li ng-repeat="x in names | filter:test track by $index ">
     {{x}}
</li>
```

A suggestion to combat the `[filter:notarray]` problem in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/filter/notarray) is to use `toArray:false`.

```
<li ng-repeat="x in names | toArray:false | filter:test track by $index ">
     {{x}}
</li>
```